# How to exclude or trim blank cells from datagridview using RowFilter in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datasource, rowfilter

I'm trying to find a way to delete or trim blank cells in my datagridview on import. I found a few things online about the rowfilter that works with the data source. Right now this is how I'm declaring my data source

```
 DataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables(0).DefaultView
```

If anyone can give me some suggestions or tell me how to trim the blank cells with the row filter I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to delete the rows with blank cells you could hide them easily with LINQ:

```
Public Sub HideDataGridViewCells(ByVal dgv As DataGridView)
    Dim EmptyCells = (From Cell As DataGridViewCell In (From Row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)() Select Row.Cells).Cast(Of DataGridViewCell)() Where Trim(Cell.Value.ToString).Equals("") Select Cell)
    For Each Cell As DataGridViewCell In EmptyCells
        Cell.OwningRow.Visible = False
    Next
End Sub
```